# Challenges Processing TEM Images with Colmap

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration, colmap

I am currently facing a challenge with using Colmap for handling Transmission Electron Microscopy (TEM) images, and I'm seeking guidance or insights from anyone familiar with this issue.

I have been using Colmap successfully for other types of images, but when attempting to process TEM images, I encountered unexpected difficulties. Despite following the standard procedures and parameter adjustments, the results obtained from Colmap seem suboptimal or even erroneous. The problem might lie in the specific characteristics of TEM images, such as low signal-to-noise ratios, high contrast, and unique imaging distortions, which might not be effectively handled by the default settings of Colmap.

I have already explored various avenues to resolve the problems, such as experimenting with different feature extractors, adjusting keypoint matching algorithms, and adjusting Colmap parameters, but the results remain unsatisfactory.

If anyone has encountered similar issues while using Colmap with TEM images or has expertise in working with TEM data in other photogrammetry software, I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to tackle this challenge.

Alternatively, if you could recommend specialized software or plugins that are better suited for handling TEM images, I would be eager to explore those options as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **solution**, I found a workaround, which was my master thesis.

Here is the git repo for more details [here](https://github.com/Mithunjack/Thesis-NeRFs).

Don't forget to put a Star if you like the work.